# Fastest way to open a Maximized New Window using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, web

What's the *fastest* way to open a new window **(Maximized)** using JavaScript and/or JQuery that's preferably compatible with most browsers?

Comment: This is blocked by most browsers now, for good reason.

Comment: does it have to be maximized? Or would it be okay if it had screen width and height?

Comment: Screen width and height would be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.moveTo(0,0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);

</script>
```