# How to open maximized window with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using Javascript's `self.open()` to open a link in a new window and i'd like that window to be maximized. I tried the `fullscreen=yes` option, which really doesn't do what I want. I am using below code:

```
self.open(pageLoc,popUpName,'height=1600,width=1800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes');
```

If i also mention `fullscreen=yes`, then window opens up like you press F11. But i don't want it that. What i want is when i double click on **IE** and click maximize icon on top right corner.

As i have given the `height` and `width` value so large, it is close to maximized window but not actual maximized window. (the reason i am saying this because
    even now if i click maximize button, it further expans little bit)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4378444/693207)

Comment: @Juren Thelen. As i mentioned even after given large height and width, it does not give actual maximized effect.

Comment: @Jürgen i think that may be the answer.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
var params = [
    'height='+screen.height,
    'width='+screen.width,
    'fullscreen=yes' // only works in IE, but here for completeness
].join(',');
     // and any other options from
     // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

var popup = window.open('http://www.google.com', 'popup_window', params); 
popup.moveTo(0,0);
```

Please refrain from opening the popup unless the user really wants it, otherwise they will curse you and blacklist your site. ;-)

**edit**: Oops, as Joren Van Severen points out in a comment, this may not take into account taskbars and window decorations (in a possibly browser-dependent way). Be aware. It seems that ignoring height and width (only param is `fullscreen=yes`) seems to work on Chrome and perhaps Firefox too; the original 'fullscreen' functionality has been disabled in Firefox for being obnoxious, but has been replaced with maximization. This directly contradicts information on the same page of https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open which says that window-maximizing is impossible. This 'feature' may or may not be supported depending on the browser.

Comment: This opens a window greater than a regular maximized window. The height of a maximized window is screen.height - height of taskbar (and some of the window decorations too it seems).

Comment: Which is screen.availHeight resp. screen.availWidth. Anyways the size still doesn't exactly fit...

Answer (score 14):

```
 window.open('your_url', 'popup_name','height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + ',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes')
```

Comment: only thing changed is window instead of self. Whats the difference?

Answer (score 8):

The best solution I could find *at present time* to open a window maximized is (Internet Explorer 11, Chrome 49, Firefox 45):

```
  var popup = window.open("your_url", "popup", "fullscreen");
  if (popup.outerWidth < screen.availWidth || popup.outerHeight < screen.availHeight)
  {
    popup.moveTo(0,0);
    popup.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
  }
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/8xwocrp6/7/

**Note 1**: It does not work on Edge (13.1058686). Not sure whether it's a bug or if it's as designed (I've filled [a bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7205972/), we'll see what they have to say about it). Here is a workaround:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge\/\d+/g))
{
    return window.open("your_url", "popup", "width=" + screen.width + ",height=" + screen.height);
}
```

**Note 2**: `moveTo` or `resizeTo` will not work (Access denied) if the window you are opening is on another domain.

Answer (score 1):

If I use Firefox  then `screen.width` and `screen.height` works fine but in IE and Chrome they  don't work properly instead it opens with the minimum size.

And yes I tried giving too large numbers too like `10000` for both `height` and `width` but not exactly the maximized effect.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this jquery window plugin: http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/

```
// create a window
sampleWnd = $.window({
   .....
});

// resize the window by passed w,h parameter
sampleWnd.resize(screen.width, screen.height);
```