# Window.open with maximize size

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

```
 URL = "window.open('../GBY/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx?ReportParams=" + ReportParams + "&ReportName=" + ReportName + "  ' , '_blank');";

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(UpdatePanel), "OPEN_WINDOW", URL, true);
```

We use above code to open report viewer in another window. But that window open not maximized size. I want to open as maximize size. How to do that with above code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297168/how-to-open-maximized-window-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.open('index.html','_blank','fullscreen=yes');
```

Try this

```
function openWin()
{
myWindow = window.open("","","width=100,height=100"); // Opens a new window
}

function resizeWin()
{
 myWindow.resizeTo(250,250);                           // Resizes the new window
 myWindow.focus();                                     // Assures that the new window gets      focus
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But it('fullscreen=yes') open as whole screen. I want the window in maximized size.

Comment: try the editted part...change 250 to ur required size...