# javascript (window.open) opens maximized in all browsers but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, popup

I am using the following code to open a maximized pop up window, i don't want to open it full screen (F11), I need it just maximized, exactly like pressing the button between minimize and close.

```
<a  onclick="javascript:w= window.open('https://www.facebook.com/mywifemylove','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank">Maximized on Chrome</a>
```

It's working fine for all browsers but not Chrome, Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp0aty2k/) for testing

Comment: That's for IE, Isn't it?

Comment: I need it maximized, Is there any way to do that? my code works fine for all browsers, Why not chrome?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me FF...

Comment: I don't want it full screen, Just maximized.

Comment: I am using FF V31, and the example in jsfiddle  works fine.

Comment: Exactly, like you pressed the button between minimize and close.

Comment: I'm running an older version of FF on this computer and it doesn't maximize. I'll try it when I'm on a machine with an up to date version. I'm surprised though since they explicitly say it shouldn't work.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I believe they meant fullscreen (F11)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work on FF 32.0 on my Windows 8 machine either. So, whatever is making it work for you isn't standard. (we are looking at the same fiddle right?)

Comment: Any solution finalized?

Answer (score 10):

With the exception of IE, browsers do not support going fullscreen with JS. This is intentional:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open#FAQ

> "All browser manufacturers try to make the opening of new secondary
>   windows noticed by users and noticeable by users to avoid confusion,
>   to avoid disorienting users."

You can manually set the size of the window to the screen size but you may have to deal with things like frame border thickness.

Relevant SO question:
[How to open maximized window with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297168/how-to-open-maximized-window-with-javascript)

Working code for max size window on latest versions of IE, FF or Chrome:

```
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com','_blank','height='+screen.height+', width='+screen.width);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open window tab with below code:-

```
window.open(src, "newWin", "width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function openMax() { 
var wihe = 'width='+screen.availWidth+',height='+screen.availHeight; 
window.open("ht*p://www.example.com/", 
"foo", 
"screenX=1,screenY=1,left=1,top=1," + wihe); 
}
```

Comment: That's good, It's full screen but the icon's still not maximized, and the window will be behind the start bar, Is there any way to make it maximized?

Comment: Oh, And not compatible with IE, Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

I think following code is helpful to you.

```
<a  id="popupLink" href="#"> link name</a> 
       jquery.click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var newTab =window.open('','_blank','channelmode=1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
        newTab.location = "https://www.facebook.com/mywifemylove";
        newTab.focus();
});
```

Comment: This response makes no sense. It is not even a valid example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can actually use it in chrome. I've also tried it but couldn't get it to work in chrome.

I know it is really helpful to actually make it maximize more quickly that makes it so the user don't have to click the button but that is how chrome works.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suwyafje/#editor:%7E:text=height%3D%24%7Bscreen.height%7D%2Cwidth%3D%24%7Bscreen.width%7D%60) example that will be as close as possible to maximization. It is always good to try to make alternative options. Here is the code from the *onclick* attribute. You can insert all your previous code to that argument as well, just removed that to show what I changed to it.

```
javascript:w= window.open('https://www.facebook.com/mywifemylove','_blank',`height=${screen.height},width=${screen.width}`);
```

Here is also a [w3School](http://jsfiddle.net/suwyafje/#editor:%7E:text=height%3D%24%7Bscreen.height%7D%2Cwidth%3D%24%7Bscreen.width%7D%60) documentation of the arguments as well, just in case you wanna look through it and see what's supported and what is not.