# I want to open the new window in browser on the click of button in maximize mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried `window.open()` and `resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height)` but it is not opening in maximize view.

Please help with the relevant code.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? I want to see the approach you are using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172748/how-to-show-fullscreen-popup-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can `resizeTo()` only the window, that was created by `window.open()`. First of all you should create and write to any var your window instance. And after that you can use its methods. Here is an example:

```
myExternalWindow = window.open("http://myurl.domain", "myWindowName", "resizable");
myExternalWindow.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
```

Good luck!

Comment: JavaScript has no way to minify or maximize a window. These OS-level functions are hidden from Frontend-developers. [source](https://javascript.info/popup-windows) or [another-source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797203/9075864)

Answer (score -1):

Try window.open with screen.availHeight / screen.availWidth.

e.g.

```
window.open(src, "newWin", "width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight)
```

Comment: it will open a new page with maximum size not in maximize mode

Answer (score -1):

The size of the window (I think you mean a popup window) you'll open can be set through the attributes **width** and **height** like below:

```
<a href="your-http-address.php" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow',
  'toolbar=no,
   location=no,
   status=no,
   menubar=no,
   scrollbars=yes,
   resizable=yes,
   width=your_width,
   height=your_height');
 return false;">Open PopUp Window</a>
```

Where the placeholder *your_width* and *your_height* specify the popup dimensions. To make the popup cover the entire screen dimensions, just use screen.availWidth and screen.availHeight.