# On Asp.net Button click open link in new maximized window

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a button in Update panel in my page. on button click event dependendant on the text boxes entered i m buliding an url and have to open that url in new window.

i have tried:

i) window open .. but it opens un maximized , not a fully maximized window. i tried setting its height to screen hieght,,but the requirement is full window only, shouldnt need to be maximize every time i open window.

```html
 <Asp:button OnClick="Btn1_Click" />

//in code behind
protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      //my code to generate url

// In below lines im trying to open window
//Im ont using OnClientClick becoz..the button is in Update panel
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnLoadReport.Page,
                             Btn1.GetType(), "", "window.open('" + myUrl+ "','','height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + ',resizable=yes,scrollbar=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,top=0, left=0');", true);
  }
```

or can i create a hyperlink click event dynamically on button click event.. and how do i try that?

any ideas and samples would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Ahmed

Comment: oh wait are you saying you did a resonse.redirect and its not running your OpenUrl() function? ofcourse it doesnt. How will it run if it already redirected to a different page. Try registering script instead.

Comment: yes tht was a mistake : ..... Thank u all guys, Window.open is no help for me. it opens popup window. and i need full(maximzed) window(not with setting hiegth, width)

Comment: i dont need a pop up window(which is not a full sized window). i need a maximized window.

Comment: it is close to maximized window but not actual maximized window. it will go to real maximized window when i double click on IE or click maximize icon. sorry for confusing u

Answer (score 0):

try this: `OnClientClick="window.open('url')"`

Comment: I have alreday used that..as mentioned in my question it always opens popup window.. i need full window

Comment: I found simmilar problem no stackoverflow, check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297168/how-to-open-maximized-window-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this please : `window.open(url, '_blank');`

EDIT : look at this link dude [example for opening new tab](http://jsfiddle.net/77hup0oo/1/)

Comment: this is not helping me get maximized window :(

Answer (score 0):

the c# file you write,

button.attributes.add("onclick","javascript:function1()");

in the aspx page,write the below javascript function

function function1()
{
 window.open("pagename",other attributes whose values are to be passed to other page);
}

Answer (score 0):

Did not understand you the first time. Try this. Im guessing your not using update panels here right? cause if you are you should use scriptmanger.register.. instead of client script

```
Btn1_Click()
{

//my code to bulid url

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Redirection","window.open('www.google.com', '_blank')",true);
}


 <Asp:button OnClick="Btn1_Click" />
```

Comment: theres is no issue registering script and opening window now. But i need a fully maximized window, which am not able to with window.open

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by adding 'chromemode=yes' in parameters.. like below..

window.open(url, 'chromemode=yes, scrollbars=yes' );

thank  you all for your answers :)