# window size is not working

Tags: javascript, html

here is my code

```
function openWin() {

    var height = screen.availHeight;
    var width = screen.availWidth ;

    var mainWin = window
            .open(
                    "terms.do",
                    "mainApplicationWindow",
                    "width="
                            + width
                            + ",height="
                            + height
                            + ",fullscreen=yes,top=0,left=0,location=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes");

    mainWin.focus();


}.
```

It should open a window with width and height of  maximum but for some odd reason its opening a window with a same width and height of parent window  . [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297168/how-to-open-maximized-window-with-javascript) post shows similar problem but in my case it does not work what am I doing wrong

Comment: yeah, you're using screen width and height...

Comment: how to fix it @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal

Comment: what width you want to it, define...

Comment: browser should be as per desktops full screen

Comment: No i have tried that it does not work with my problem I want to know what am i doing wrong @Circadian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use

```
var height = screen.height;
```

and

```
var width = screen.width;
```

instead.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297168/how-to-open-maximized-window-with-javascript) older post answers your questions well.

Comment: it returns undefined