# force maximum browser size on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to use JavaScript to detect if the user's browser is minimized *(not completely minimized -- just reduced size to smaller then maximize)* at all, and if it is then > force **full screen** > upon page **load** of website.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if (smaller then max screen) {
   screen = 100%; // general idea
});
```

Comment: _“upon page load of website (as soon as URL is accessed)”_ – how would that even happen, if the browser is minimized?

Comment: I personally dislike *all* websites that maximize themselves -- I want to be in control of the size of my windows. That said, go here for maximization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297168/how-to-open-maximized-window-with-javascript and here for detecting minimization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328665/how-to-detect-browser-minimize-and-maximize-state-in-javascript

Comment: As I think you already know, this is bad ux. Why do you think the user will need full screen forced on them? What does the page show?

Comment: maximized is different than full screen. You won't be able to switch to true full screen without user intervention because of security concerns. (Imagine that a full screen window mimicked the desktop and requested credentials)

Comment: Please, don't use this. It is fine as a project, but it will be trully annoying for the general public, and it would make your site have a terribly bad reputation.

Comment: Well I was mostly just curious.

Comment: @Cbroe terminology typo, has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to detect change of size, here's how to do it,using jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  //...
});
```

And here's how to maximize the browser window :

```
window.moveTo(0, 0);
window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

But really, I would not encourage it, as it's better that the user controls the browsing experience.

Comment: As a sidenote, `window.resizeTo` and `window.moveTo` are controlled by browser options, user can choose, if a web page can use these methods.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu.In chrome, how do I disable the use of `window.resizeTo` and `window.moveTo`?