# JavaScript redirect user to new page

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a web app using Firebase and Vanilla JavaScript. Let's say I have home page index.html, when user clicks to sign in, a popup appears where he will enter details. Since he signs in it means the URL should be `localhost:5000/signin`. Is it possible to do it with JavaScript from frontend or is there a need to add Node.js to redirect user respectively.
I am confused how this works and would appreciate if someone could explain how should I approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the url without changing or reloading the page in modern browsers.

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'Signin', '/signin');
```

Or you can use replaceState since you are using modal, however it will break back button functionality.

Please look at [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<script>
    function signin() {
        window.open("/signin", "_blank", "width=500,height=300")
    } 
</script>
```

You can change width and height to your sign-in page width and height. Also, you can add some other properties to your popup. For more information visit https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
This also might be helpful if you want to make your page maximized [How to open maximized window with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297168/how-to-open-maximized-window-with-javascript)